# Looking for dataset to test FULLTEXT style searches on

Tags: mysql, database, core-data, dataset, corpus

I am looking for a corpus of text to run some trial fulltext style data searches across. Either something I can download, or a system that generates it. Something a bit more random would be better e.g. 1,000,000 wikipedia articles in a format easy to insert into a 2 column database (id, text).

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Try http://pizzachili.dcc.uchile.cl/texts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll throw this out there since I'm familiar with it - Prosper.com makes their member loan listings available for analysis [through an XML export](http://www.prosper.com/tools/DataExport.aspx).  The export would have about 50,000 loan requests with descriptions and over 1,000,000 member profiles (although many of those are empty).

Comment: Thanks, this could be useful. Still quite a bit of processing to get it to work - but will give it a go.

Answer (score 5):

Project Gutenberg has 32000 books available.

**Edit:**
As of now (17.06.16) there are 52,284 free ebooks to download **as plain text file in UTF-8** in a wide variety of topics (From science to religion).
Also in formats EPUB, Kindle or html format.
Check [here Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: Where one could access the boos in TXT file format?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [Wikipedia dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database)?

Comment: Mainly because uncompressed it is many many GB and is in markup language - just looking for text.