# Where can I find a huge amount of text files?

Tags: text, text-files, text-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Looking for dataset to test FULLTEXT style searches on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095813/looking-for-dataset-to-test-fulltext-style-searches-on)

I am recently on to a project of Data Mining, for which I need 100 GB of plain text for testing. I am tired of searching the net the whole day. Someone please help me out by providing the links, where can I download such text files?

Comment: Are you trying download 100GB text file.....

Comment: Yep..! More than 100 GB actually.. 1TB is our target..!

Comment: Get the whole of gutenberg in one 7zip file: http://www.gutenberg-tar.com/

Comment: This may also be handy: https://blog.archive.org/2012/04/26/downloading-in-bulk-using-wget/ both for the benefit of future searchers - I realise that this question is old ;)

Comment: This link takes you directly to wiki download page: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/

Answer (score 11):

What type of text are you searching for? Conversational, articles, books - or a good spread of everything?

Project Gutenberg might be a good start:
http://www.gutenberg.org/

Wikipedia also allows you to download an archive of articles:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: Yep... anykind of text files is Okay... yes.. conversational, articles, documentaries, novels.. etc...!

Comment: Project Gutenberg would probably be your best bet, there are over 38,000 free books on there. Most of them can be downloaded as plain text files.

Comment: Is there a better way...instead of downloading each text file one after the other.. can i get a zipped file whose size is of the order of 1GB??

Answer (score 5):

you should use http://dumps.wikimedia.org/

Comment: can u please provide me a specific link..! n i saw a zipped file of xml format thats around 230 GB. Heres the link.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download.. before downloading i would like to know what exactly is present inside it.. ps: we are looking for text files that has got some meaningful text... like conversations, documentaries, etc..!

Comment: it is actually dump file of the dump file of the Wikimedia.and generally it contain Wikipedia article in xml format.so u can check it.I think it should be helpful to you.